# Attackers might be trying to steal your information from (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, security, certificate

I'm getting the following error for one specific website (and only one specific website):

[image]

I've tried the following:

- Making sure my time / data settings are correct
- Clearing all browsing data
- Deleting and reinstalling Chrome

Nothing works. Interestingly, I only get this error for one specific site (www.datacamp.com). And when I turn off wi-fi and tether my iPhone, I'm able to get through to the site. When I turn my wi-fi back on, I get errors again.

When I view details I see this:

[image]

And when I view the certificate I see this:

[image]

I've tried deleting the certificate, but I get the following message:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why it took me so long to try this. I just unplugged my modem and router, then plugged them back in. At least for now, it seems to have resolved the issue...

Answer (score 31):

If you are getting this error when access localhost, simply go to

```
chrome://flags/
```

and enable **Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost**.

Comment: this was exactly what I was trying to find in chrome's menus

Answer (score 1):

Check your connection's DNS entries.  It's likely a adware or malware program modified them.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Google DNS `8.8.8.8` and the Cloudflare DNS `1.1.1.1` solved my issue.

[image: adding-google-cloudflare-dns]

Answer (score 0):

open network and sharing center
On the left side- click on:
change advanced sharing settings.
click on home or work.
go through and check "turn off" for the first three questions.
turn on password.
Your computer connection was wide open!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response AJ93. Unfortuantely, I have a Mac - not a PC. There is no "network and sharing center."

Comment: try method given in this website [link](http://www.zerodollartips.com/your-connection-is-not-private-chrome/)

Comment: Last but not least, use Safari instead of Chrome, see if the problem persists.

Comment: Same problem in Safari and FireFox. But like I said, if I turn off my wi-fi and connect to the internet by tethering my iPhone, it works fine. That has to mean something, right?

Comment: If your wifi is public, can you change your wi-fi to private and have password on it, Public WiFi hotspots are insecure and prone to hacking attempts. Hackers can monitor internet packets on WiFi and decrypt SSL to steal your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing DNS worked for me in Windows 10. Simply open powershell and issue this command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```